# Babel and Lerna Setup issue on different environemnts

Tags: javascript, node.js, lerna

I am trying to structure my project based on lerna.js now as per documentation
everything is setup and is working fine when run as development server following is directory
structure.

```
index.js
packages/
  package1
  package2
    index.js => contains: import Package1 from 'package1' <--- Package1 etc path is managed by lerna.
  package3
```

DEV & BUILD Command

```
# Build
  "build::js": "babel ./packages --out-dir ./build --ignore node_modules",
  "build::nonjs": "babel ./package1 --out-dir ./build/package1 --copy-files",
  "build": "rm -rf ./build && mkdir ./build && npm run build::js && npm run build::nonjs"

# Dev
  "dev:nodemon": "DEBUG=*,-babel,-babel:*,-express:*,-nodemon:*,-nodemon,-snapdragon:*,-finalhandler,-follow-redirects nodemon -L --exec babel-node --inspect index.js",
  "dev": "yarn dev:nodemon",
```

Now runing dev command on my project works fine but when files are build for production than babel doesnt change Package1 path to its absolute location just like regular module.

```
...
var _Cache = _interopRequireDefault(require("package1")); // <<---- how to get ride of this problem. as. node tires to locate module but there is no package1 in node_modules its just regular modules which is inside packages/ directory. now running it on dev simply works.
```

Comment: If you're importing `package1` it should be a dependency set in `package.json` which contains the location of the module.

Comment: So than why lerna.js is working when dev uses workspace defined in package.json....instead of installing module which were defined in packages/

Comment: or in simple terms is there any other solution apart from installing each module one by one on production build

Comment: Why would you install them one by one?